# JavaScript/HTML5 Canvas - Load array of images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a folder of images, altogether 32x32 tiles. I am trying to load these images using JavaScript, onto an HTML5 canvas.

Here's what I have:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();
    var tiles = [];

    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 352;


    for (x = 0; x <= 520; x++) {
        imageObj.src = "line_tile/t"+x+".png";
        tiles.push(imageObj);
    } 

    var theX;
    var theY;
    for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {

            theX = x*32;
            theY = y*32;

            context.drawImage(tiles[2], theY, theX,32,32);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+theX+" | Y Pos: "+theY);
        }
    } 
};
```

The problem is that this code only loads up the last tile (in this case `tile[520]`). In reality I want to load all the tiles. No matter what. How do I properely put a set of images into an array and load it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your modifying a single instance of imageObj; so basically you end up with an array all pointing to the same instance, which ends with 520.

try

```
for (x = 0; x <= 520; x++) {
    var imageObj = new Image(); // new instance for each image
    imageObj.src = "line_tile/t"+x+".png";
    tiles.push(imageObj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not strictly related to your problem but you might encounter it (with current code)

I'm not sure if you do not need first to see if the Image was actually loaded **before** adding it to the tiles array.